# Objective-C Protocols Not Sending Message

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, delegates, protocols

I have read around, and it seems as though delegates would be really useful in my app. Unfortunately, every tutorial about protocols I have tried has failed - the delegate is not receiving the message! It would be great if someone could tell me what I'm doing wrong.

I created a really simple test app with two ViewControllers, a FirstViewController and a SecondViewController. I have set them up in container views to see the effect properly.
My Main.storyboard looks like this:

[image: Main.storybord]

The purpose of the test app is to change the background colour of the SecondViewController when one of the buttons is pressed in the FirstViewController.

Here is FirstViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol FirstViewControllerDelegate

-(void)colourDidChange:(UIColor *)theColour;

@end

@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController{

    UIButton *redButton;
    UIButton *blueButton;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) id <FirstViewControllerDelegate> delegate;

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *redButton;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *blueButton;

-(IBAction)redPressed;
-(IBAction)bluePressed;
```

My FirstViewController.m:

```
#import "FirstViewController.h"

@interface FirstViewController ()

@end

@implementation FirstViewController

@synthesize redButton, blueButton;
@synthesize delegate;

-(IBAction)redPressed{
    [self.delegate colourDidChange:[UIColor redColor]];
}
-(IBAction)bluePressed{
    [self.delegate colourDidChange:[UIColor blueColor]];
}

-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

I think I have implemented the protocol and the calling of the delegate correctly.

Here is my SecondViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "FirstViewController.h"

@interface SecondViewController : UIViewController <FirstViewControllerDelegate> 

-(void)colourDidChange:(UIColor *)theColour;
```

And my SecondViewController.m:

```
-(void)colourDidChange:(UIColor *)theColour{
    self.view.backgroundColor = theColour;
}

-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    FirstViewController *firstView = [[FirstViewController alloc]init];
    firstView.delegate = self;
}
```

I have breakpointed the project and realised that `colourDidChange:` in the SecondViewController is never executed.
It would be much appreciated if someone could point out what I have done wrong, whether declaring (or conforming to) the delegate poorly or not setting the delegate the right way.

Many thanks.

Comment: Where did you breakpoint? In -colourDidChange:? or in -redPressed/-bluePressed? That may help to determine where things broke down, e.g. if in the actions, perhaps delegate was nil thus why things didn't progress along. I can see a couple errors: 1. delegate properties are a weak property ('weak' or 'assign'), not a retain/strong. Also, IBAction's should have a signature of -(IBAction):foo:(id)sender; your actions lack the 'id' argument.

Comment: I breakpointed both - when blue/redPressed was called, the self.delegate was 0x0. Setting variables from another class has never worked for me.

Comment: OK. My guess is you may have 2 FirstViewController instances, especially since the 'firstView' created in your SectionViewController isn't necessarily created in a typical way. Since you're using Storyboards, you could try exposing the delegate as an IBOutlet and hooking it up in the storyboard instead of in -viewDidLoad.

Comment: You should watch the WWDC sessions on Modern Objective C. Your code is the pre modern way.

Comment: @JohnC.Daub How can you do that?

Comment: In FirstViewController.h, declare delegate as an IBOutlet (add that to the property declaration). Then in the Storyboard you should be able to control-click-drag from the FirstViewController to the SecondViewController and set the Second as the First's delegate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are honestly very close. Container views will call the prepareForSegue: method, so you should be initializing the second view controller's delegate in this method:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"TypeContainerViewSegueNameHere"]) {
        SecondViewController *viewController = (SecondViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        viewController.delegate = self;
    }
}
```

This way you know that you are getting the instance of SecondViewController that will be in use. Also, you do not need to redeclare the delegate method in your SecondViewController.h file:

```
-(void)colourDidChange:(UIColor *)theColour;
```

Finally, in storyboard set the title of the container view segue to SecondViewController to whatever title you like and then copy paste that title to where 'TypeContainerViewSegueNameHere' is written above.

**EDIT 1:**

A typical situation would be similar to this:

```
@protocol ViewControllerDelegate;

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) id<ViewControllerDelegate>delegate;

@end

@protocol ViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>

- (void) delegateMethod;

@end

...

@implementation ViewController

- (void) buttonAction:(id)sender {
    [self.delegate delegateMethod];
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"TypeContainerViewSegueNameHere"]) {
        SecondViewController *viewController = (SecondViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        viewController.delegate = self;
    }
}

@end

...

@interface SecondViewController : UIViewController <ViewControllerDelegate>

@end

...

@implementation SecondViewController

- (void)delegateMethod {

}

@end
```

That said, you could make your main view controller the delegate of your FirstViewController, which has the two view containers as seen in your screenschot. And then call a delegate method from the main view controller to the second view controller. Although I am curious as to why you have these two view controllers as child view controllers rather than placing a view and two buttons in one view controller.

**EDIT 2:**

Here is an example (written quickly and not tested). Think of it as a triangle of delegates:

```
@protocol FirstViewControllerDelegate;

@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) id<FirstViewControllerDelegate>delegate;

@end

@protocol FirstViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>

- (void) firstViewControllerDelegateMethod;

@end

...

@implementation FirstViewController

- (void) buttonAction:(id)sender {
    [self.delegate firstViewControllerDelegateMethod];
}

@end

...

@protocol MainViewControllerDelegate;

@interface MainViewController : UIViewController <FirstViewControllerDelegate>

@end

@protocol MainViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>

- (void) mainViewControllerDelegateMethod;

@end

...

@implementation MainViewController

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"TypeContainerViewSegueNameHere"]) {
        SecondViewController *viewController = (SecondViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        viewController.delegate = self.delegate;
    }
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"TypeContainerViewSegueNameHere"]) {
        FirstViewController *viewController = (FirstViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        viewController.delegate = self;
    }
}

- (void)firstViewControllerDelegateMethod {
    [self.delegate mainViewControllerDelegateMethod];
}

@end

...

@interface SecondViewController : UIViewController <MainViewControllerDelegate>

@end

...

@implementation SecondViewController

- (void)mainViewControllerDelegateMethod {

}

@end
```

Like I said, you should think about reducing the complexity of this section of your app and consider putting all of your views in one view controller.

Comment: I put that code in the SecondViewController.m, except I changed the code around because I want SecondViewController to be the delegate of FirstViewController, not the other way around. However it still didn't work. My normal app does not use container views, so how would you do this without them?

Comment: Thank you for the edit, number 1 worked for me. How would you do this if, for example, you were creating an iPad app and wanted to pass data over from a popover like a UIImagePickerController delegate?

Comment: If it worked, you may want to select it as an answer and post a separate question for "want to pass data over from a popover like a UIImagePickerController delegate" You will get a response from more people than just me and it is a valid question to be have its own thread. The general idea will be that UIImagePickerControllerDelegate will call back to the view controller that presented the UIImagePickerController, then handle the callback method.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect that there are 2 instances of `FirstViewController`, one created by your storyboard and another one created in `SecondViewController`'s `viewDidLoad` method.

When the`FirstViewController` creates `SecondViewController` it could set the delegate property or use an Outlet to connect them.

Note: delegate properties should not be `retain`, they should be `assign` (or `weak` with ARC).

Comment: Thanks for the retain tip! I'm not sure what you mean when you say FirstViewController creates SecondViewController - they both exist in separate container views.

Comment: Well, whoever creates the SecondViewController should set its delegate property.  Depends how your program is structured.  Your code shows that SecondsViewController is creating the FirstViewController, which doesn't make sense.